# Eisenstein series of Hilbert modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms, eisenstein-series

I am reading Shimura's paper "The Special Values of the Zeta Functions Associated With Hilbert Modular Forms" and I do not exactly understand his definition of the Eisenstein series in section 3.

Can someone refer me to another paper that explains this construction of Eisenstein series of a Hilbert modular form of totally real field extensions more clearly? I am mostly interested in the case of a quadratic field extension.

Comment: May be section 2 of Samit Dasgupta, Henri Darmon, and Robert Pollack 
Hilbert modular forms and the Gross-Stark conjecture 
Annals of Math. (2) 174 (2011), no. 1, 439-484. In the homepage of Henri Darmon there is a pdf...

Comment: Tim Atwill and I described this construction in our paper "Newform theory for Hilbert Eisenstein series" (available at http://www.benjaminlinowitz.com/papers/hilberteisenstein.pdf). See for instance sections 2 and 3. I also agree with Xarles that the paper of Dasgupta, Darmon and Pollack contains a very nice (and concrete) description of the construction of Hilbert Eisenstein series.

Comment: @Xarles Thank you! Dasgupta, Darmon, and Pollack explicitly compute the constant term of the Fourier expansion of the Eisenstein series. Do you know if/where I can find a similar computation of the non constant terms?